# MacRuby NSTextView adding text hangs program

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macruby

I have NSTextView that i add text to using

```
def puts(val)
    storage = @output.textStorage
    storage.beginEditing
    storage.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString.alloc.initWithString(val+"\n"))
    storage.endEditing
end
```

This works for few times but at some point in time it hangs the whole program (spinning ball of death).

I'm calling this method from MacRuby thread so i think that it has something to do with it.

Comment: You shouldn't need those `beginEditing` and `endEditing` calls.

Comment: I've tried using @output.setString(val) instead but that doesn't change the situation

Comment: Why are you using threads? Do you have an expensive process? NSThread or ruby Thread implementation?

Comment: Hope my answers are not so dumb or useless for your problem ;)

Comment: Could you try using NSThread instead?

Comment: @microspino no, sorry i don't have a working sample now and due to this problem decided to implement my app another way so i can't check your answer, also it's highly possible cause i was using Net::HTTP.get and it might be the case so i'll just accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the `string` property of my `NSTextView` called `home_text` by

```
home_text.string = "a very loooooong string"
```

I've Never had a "beach volleyball/pizza of death". When I'm not sure I can rely on a default value I add a control on the string I want to add to the `NSTextView` to avoid setting it to a nil value. Basic stuff here, I know sorry!

Are you doing any I/O operation, in your main thread or somewhere else, without using Cocoa most robust Asynchronous APIs? Like downloading stuff from the web which , for example, would be performed more safely using `NSURLDownload` instead of either

`Net::HTTP.get('...a url...','..a path..")`

or

```
download_url = NSURl.UrlWithString '...a url...'
download_data = NSMutableStringalloc.initWithContentsOfUrl(download_url, 
                                                           encoding:..., 
                                                            error:...)
```

that are synchronous.
This could explain the randomness of your problem, although it's just one of the possible causes.